# coefficient of variation for a proportion

Tags: proportion, coefficient-of-variation

I'm new to the coefficient of variation. I'm trying to get at the precision of estimate. Using my software (Stata) I have an estimated percentage of 25% and a reported CV of 18. couple of questions:

1. Does the CV make sense for a proportion? I've only seen it for counts.
2. Is the CV of 18 interpreted as 18%?

thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what it might mean to "interpret" 18 as 18?  Or better: what would it mean *not* to interpret 18 as 18?

Comment: My apology. I meant to interpret the CV of 18 (from my software) as 18%. I will correct in the post.

Comment: Stata's documentation tends to be good.  What does it say for whatever command it is that produced this output?

Comment: It says cv requests that the coefficient of variation be displayed for each cell proportion, count, or row or column proportion. estat cv reports the coefficient of variation (CV) for each coefficient in the current estimation results. The CV for coefficient b is
CV(b) = SE(b) / |b| × 100%